# Failed dependencies: error when installing openssl from rpm

Tags: linux, openssl, rpm, rhel

I need to upgrade my openssl (my current version is OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
). My box is not connected to internet. So I download Openssl rpm and execute

```
rpm -Uvh openssl-1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

Command. Then I got following error.

```
warning: openssl-1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 246110c1: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-40.fc20 is needed by openssl-1:1.0.1e-40.fc20.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) qt-1:4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) wget-1.12-1.8.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) bind-libs-32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) bind-utils-32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) fipscheck-1.2.0-7.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.20.2-9.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) pyOpenSSL-0.10-2.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-ldap-0:2.3.10-1.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) openssh-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ntpdate-4.2.6p5-1.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ntp-4.2.6p5-1.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) certmonger-0.61-3.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) openssh-clients-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) openssh-server-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) tcpdump-14:4.0.0-3.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) perl-Crypt-SSLeay-0.57-16.el6.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) nginx-1.6.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit) is needed by (installed) nginx-1.6.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by (installed) nginx-1.6.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) qt-1:4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) wget-1.12-1.8.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.20.2-9.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) pyOpenSSL-0.10-2.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-rhsm-1.9.6-1.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-ldap-0:2.3.10-1.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) perl-Crypt-SSLeay-0.57-16.el6.x86_64
libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by (installed) nginx-1.6.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by (installed) nginx-1.6.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
```

I understood that is a collision with dependencies. What is the way to achieve me to update my openssl in offline mode ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to satisfy all dependencies that would get broken by the upgrade.

Since apparently all those packages mentioned require that specific version of `libcrypto`, which again does not seem to be present inside the `rpm` you are trying to install, this leaves only one solution: you'd have to upgrade *all* those packages to versions accepting the newer `openSSL` version themselves.

This is a typical example of what is often called the "dependency hell" you can run into using dependency aware software management systems like `rpm`. Though that situation indeed appears annoying, there is a very good reason for it and no real way around it. The `rpm` command offers a "force" option to install that package despite all those failed dependency warnings. But in the end all those packages *will* be broken, so such installation more or less breaks your system. So that is not an option.

You *could* try to collect more and more packages and install them offline together with that `openSSL` package. But that is a very cumbersome tasks. Do yourself a favor and *somehow* establish a temporary internet connection for that task. Then the package management system can sort out all those dependencies by itself.

---

Actually it occurs to me that there is one more option:

You could locally mirror the repository configured inside that target system on some other system that *does* have an internet connection. This means you have to sync (download) *all* packages in that repository together with the hierarchy and setup a local repository server which can be accessed from your target system. That way you could locally use that repository as package source with all the advantages of automatic dependency resolution. But *without* having to setup an internet connection. All you would need is a network connection to the system offering the mirrored repository. And you have to alter the configuration of your package management on the target system to use that local mirror instead of the remote one.

You could also keep up that local mirror service by syncing it on a regular (daily) base. This is what many companies actually do to reduce network traffic. That way the local mirror acts somewhat like a package proxy for local systems.

Repository mirroring is a well documented strategy. You will find a detailed explanation matching your distribution.

---

And another thought: :-)

If your problem is not that you cannot / don't want to setup an internet connection for that target system but that you cannot get *any* network connection set up, then again there is an option:

You can create a repository mirror as mentioned above, but store it on a local disk. For example a usb hard drive. That way you can then attach and mount that repository into the local file system on the target system and configure your package management such that it uses that local copy as a repository. That way you do not need a network connection at all on the target system.